# Why does Qt Creator use std::___LIBCPP_ABI_VERSION::string instead of std::string when I use "Add Definition to xxx.cpp"? What does this mean?

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, qt-creator, std

When I define a method which takes a `std::string` in a header file and use the "`Add Definition to xxx.cpp`" functionality in Qt Creator it creates a definition in the .cpp in which all the std::string parameters use a type `std::___LIBCPP_ABI_VERSION::string`.

Usually I just delete the "`___LIBCPP_ABI_VERSION::`", but what does this mean? Why does it happen and how do I get qt creator to simply use std::string as intended?

This is in OSX. I should add that in my .pro file I have:

```
LIBS += -stdlib=libc++
LIBS += -lstdc++
```

in order to use C++11. I'm guessing it has something to do with this use of the standard library but I don't know exactly what the issue is.

Comment: Independent of your current problem, you should not mix `libc++` and `libstdc++`. These are different libraries. Read more about the current clang C++ standard library: http://libcxx.llvm.org/#why

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you can "redirect" types and Qt Creator resolves this redirects differently, perhaps not always in the most wanted way.

Assume you have 2 types `Foo` in `Namespace1` and `Bar` in `Namespace2`. Now you can make `Bar` a type of `Namespace1` to be able to access it via `Namespace1::Bar`.

bar.h

```
#pragma once

namespace Namespace2 {

struct Bar
{
};

}
```

foo.h

```
#pragma once

#include "bar.h"

namespace Namespace1
{
    using MyBar = Namespace2::Bar; // i.e. Namespace1::MyBar
    using Namespace2::Bar;         // i.e. Namespace1::Bar

    class Foo
    {
    public:
        Foo(const Bar &bar);
        Foo(const MyBar &bar);
    };
}
```

In the foo header, both argument are types are in `Namespace1` but they are redirected in different ways (see `using` statement). For the compiler it is all the same, but Qt Creator expands the types differently into the `cpp` file.

foo.cpp

```
#include "foo.h"

namespace Namespace1 {

Foo::Foo(const Namespace2::Bar &bar)
{
}

Foo::Foo(const MyBar &bar)
{
}

}
```

In the C++ standard library on OS X, `std::string` is not implemented directly but redirected to `std::___LIBCPP_ABI_VERSION::string`, which then implements the functionality. For you as a user, that should not be visible at all because it is a implementation detail, that might change in the future. You are always working on `std::string`. You can and always should replace the type with the original type that you used in the header.

Comment: is there anything I can do to get Qt Creator to resolve the redirect as desired?

Comment: Qt Creator in general has problems "understanding" code. There is Options/C++/Codemodel where you can somehow switch from "Qt Creator internal" to a Clang code model but that is very experimental. I don't know the details since we only tested it for a very short time because it was way too slow. I'd recommend setting up a command line script using `find` and `sed` that replaces `std::___LIBCPP_ABI_VERSION::string`. You can use a custom build script in Qt creator to run it before every build.